# JavaFX: display text instead of boolean value (true/false)

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm using tableview in `JavaFX` to display `List<Contact>`.

For initialize function of the controller, the tableview columns are binded to `List<Contact>` as follow:

```
sprintName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Contact, String>("name"));
importStatus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Contact, Boolean>("imported"));
enddate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Contact, String>("endDate"));
```

However, I want to display for column `imported` instead `true/false` the text `imported/new`

Is it possible in `JavaFX` or do I have to change the type of `imported` to `String`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a cell factory (in addition to the cell value factory):

```
importStatus.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<Contact, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty ? null :
            item.booleanValue() ? "imported" : "new");
    }
});
```

See the [`Cell` class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) for general information about the cell rendering mechanism.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I tried your approach but receive another error:

`The type of setCellValueFactory(Callback<CellDataFeatures<S,T>,ObservableValue<T>>) is erroneous
  where S,T are type-variables:
    S extends Object declared in class TableColumn
    T extends Object declared in class TableColumn

incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    <anonymous TableCell<Contact,Boolean>> cannot be converted to ObservableValue<Boolean>`

Comment: @ti.voodoo  Did you confuse the method I called (`setCellFactory(...)`) for the method you already have (`setCellValueFactory(...)`). As I stated in the answer, you need both.